# Execute bat file with unix credentials and file transfer to UNIX box in javascript

Tags: javascript, shell, unix

How can I execute bat file from windows with credentials.

Checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1880198/how-to-execute-shell-command-in-javascript) solution and just curious how to pass the credentials to login to unix server and then do some steps using bat file?

```
fs.chmodSync('./myFile.bat', 0o755);

    let spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
        ls = spawn('cmd.exe',["/c", `C:\\myFile.bat`], ["","\\data\\myFromFolder"] );

    ls.stdout.on('stdout', function (error, stdout, stderr) {
            if (error) {
                console.error(error);
                return;
            }
        console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
    });
```

Basically I need to pass parameters to the bat file. from the javascrpt code.

I set some default parameters in the .bat file, But the first three param has to be local folder path, username , password

Similar to this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52689223/how-to-pass-parameters-from-exec-method-to-batch-file-using-nodejs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to run bat file passing credentials as params with below code.

```
let spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
        let bat = require.resolve('<Full path to bat file>');
        let ls = spawn(bat, ['<Full path to source folder>','username','password']);

        ls.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
            console.log('stdout: ' + data)
        });

        ls.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
            console.log('stderr: ' + data);
        });

        ls.on('exit', function (code) {
            console.log('child process exited with code ' + code);
        });
```

Supported by [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36617142)